# I am trying to use method FeatureManagement.changeProtection to make Custom Metadata Object public but it doesn't work

Tags: feature-management, change

I am trying to use method `FeatureManagement.changeProtection` to make Custom Metadata Object public but it doesn't work. I know that Custom Metadata types and Custom settings and External and Big objects reside in objects Metadata API folder, so I hoped that I could use the method `FeatureManagement.changeProtection` to control the visibility of custom metadata, but it doesn't work.

When I use the following code

```
FeatureManagement.changeProtection(String.valueOf(CustomMetadata__mdt.sobjectType), 'CustomObject', 'Unprotected');
```

I receive an error

```
Non-CustomObject Type's protection cannot be altered: CustomObject
```

When I use the following code

```
FeatureManagement.changeProtection(String.valueOf(CustomMetadata__mdt.sobjectType), 'CustomMetadata', 'Unprotected');
```

I receive another error

```
No such type: CustomMetadata
```

How can I change protection of custom metadata records using Apex?

Answer (score 1):

[`FeatureManagement.changeProtection` is available to use only with real Custom Objects and Custom permissions.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm#apex_System_FeatureManagement_changeProtection) Custom metadata types, custom settings, big objects and external objects are not supported in `FeatureManagement.changeProtection` method.